# How to check isNumeric / isNumber in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, isnumeric

How to do this simple check in JSTL (without extending any Java classes and additional JSP functions). I need it like this:

```
<c:if test="${fn:isNumeric()}">
    // do something
</c:if>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your environment supports the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking non-getter methods on EL objects (which is available in all Servlet 3.0 compatible containers, such as Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), then you could just use the [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method directly in EL.

```
<c:set var="numberAsString">${someExpressionToTestForNumber}</c:set>
<c:if test="${numberAsString.matches('[0-9]+')}">
    It's a number!
</c:if>
```

*(I'll leave the minus `-` and the thousands and fraction separators `,` and `.` outside consideration as possible characters which may appear in a technically valid number)*

Note that the `<c:set>` with the expression in its *body* implicitly converts any type to `String` using `String#valueOf()`. Otherwise the `matches()` call in `<c:if>` would fail for non-`String` types.

Answer (score 6):

If you really insist on

> (without extending any java classes and additional JSP functions)

then you could use the following hack.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:set var="x" value="8" />
<c:catch var="isNumber">
   <c:set var="x" value="${x * 1}" />
</c:catch>
<c:if test="${isNumber == null}">
    ... do something ...
</c:if>
<c:if test="${isNumber != null}">
      ... do not do anything...
</c:if>
```

Comment: I didn't know about <c:catch>, it's not a perfectly neat solution, but it does the job. One could argue that is is abusing exceptions, but if it is actually an "exception" to receive a number and you expect a number, this is actually not too bad. In many cases the code could also be simpler, more like <c:set var="n" value="0"/> <c:catch><c:set var="n" value="${input * 1}"/></c:catch>

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom function as explained in the following tutorials:

1. [Creating Custom functions in JSP using JSTL](http://anshulsood2006.blogspot.in/2012/03/creating-custom-functions-in-jsp-using.html)
2. [How to create a custom Function for JSTL](http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/)
3. [Another tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2003/jw-0523-calltag.html?page=2)

---

**Steps to create a function from the above links:**

1. Create a `.tld` file under `/WEB-INF`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
        <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
        <short-name>functionalTlds</short-name>
        <uri>http://www.rasabihari.com/functionalTlds</uri>
        <function>
            <name>isNumeric</name>
            <function-class>com.expressions.Functions</function-class>
            <function-signature>boolean isNumeric(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
        </function>
   </taglib>
   ```
2. Create a class with the method (the logic of the method is taken from [here](http://www.zparacha.com/best-way-to-check-if-a-java-string-is-a-number/#.UIVZe0b9di0), it uses [Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info))

   ```
   package com.expressions;

   /**
     *
     * @author rasabihari
     */
   public class Functions {
       public static boolean isNumeric(String number) {  
           boolean isValid = false;  
           /*
           Explaination: 
           [-+]?: Can have an optional - or + sign at the beginning. 
           [0-9]*: Can have any numbers of digits between 0 and 9 
           \\.? : the digits may have an optional decimal point. 
           [0-9]+$: The string must have a digit at the end. 
           If you want to consider x. as a valid number change  
           the expression as follows. (but I treat this as an invalid number.). 
           String expression = "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9\\.]+$"; 
           */  

           String expression = "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$";  
           CharSequence inputStr = number;  
           Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);  
           Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);  

           if(matcher.matches()){  
               isValid = true;  
           }

           return isValid;  
       }
   }
   ```
3. And then use it in the JSP as:

   ```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
   <%@taglib uri="http://www.rasabihari.com/functionalTlds" prefix="ftld" %>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <c:if test="${ftld:isNumeric('123')}">
          <!-- ... do something ...
              This block will run
           -->
       </c:if>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```